# how to get the messageProperty from Json reader?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

how to get the message from messageProperty in Ext.data.reader.Json using extjs 4.X ? 
using something like store.getProxy().getReader()..?

getMessageProperty() is available in 6.x, not in 4.x.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 4, messageProperty wasn't in the config block so `store.getProxy().getReader().messageProperty` should work.